# Java programming to interfaces shall I use it all the time, especially for collections

Tags: java, collections, interface

As suggested almost everywhere shall I be using interface all the time, especially when working with collections.

```
// Using interfaces
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
((LinkedList) list).offerFirst(num);

//Using concrete class
LinkedList list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
list.offerFirst(num);
```

In first approach compiler gives warning and even syntax seems cumbersome.

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to offerFirst(E) as a member of the raw type LinkedList
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the `offerFirst` method, perhaps you should be programming to the `Deque` interface (which represents double ended queue) instead of the `List` interface:

```
Deque<Integer> deque = new LinkedList<Integer>();
deque.offerFirst(num);
```

Comment: Okay for this case I can use Deque, in case I want to use method which is specific to the implementation then which approach I should take, first or second?

Comment: @AkshayNaik If you are using a method specific to an implementation, and there is no suitable interface containing that method, you should use the implementation type (i.e. the class). It's pointless to program to interface if you are always going to cast it back to the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

This normally is best:

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(42);

Deque<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.offerFirst(num);
```

While sometimes there is no choice.

```
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(42);
list.offerFirst(num);
```

The interface approach gives a more general algorithm with freedom of implementation,
reimplementation in the future, a greater applicability.

However that only goes as far generalisation goes.